# Register user only if Stripe payment valid

Tags: stripe-payments, registration

I have an onboarding registration workflow for my web application. I want to register the user only if Stripe payment is valid.

Here are my current steps :

1. Choose plan
2. Set personnel infos
3. Validation --> User is created
4. Pay using stripe on a new page --> User is activated

The problem is that it causes some friction, so I want to have step 3 and 4 in one step : Validation return the Stripe Payment view, and if valid it create and activate the user.

The problem is that I can't figure how to give application users informations to Stripe to create user on webhook.

I thought about create a temp user before return stripe view, but I don't think that is the best architectural choice.

Comment: Why does it *cause friction*? I think you need to store user information anyway. Consider this scenario: A (new) user enters all his information, but for some reason, cannot complete his payment *right now*. If it were me, I would like to be able to come back at a later moment, and expect the information I entered earlier to be still there. So, just create a user with some kind of Status attribute (e.g. *Pending Initial Payment*). If you want, you can periodically clean up users that are still Pending after [x] days.

Comment: @Berend has been given best scenario